# Dynamically building linq query based on UI input

Tags: linq, dynamic

I'm building a filter for my application that allows the users to filter a collection of custom objects on multiple properties. I've provided a screenshot for clarity, what I'm implementing is the light blue control on the top left:
[image]

The idea is that for each field that has the checkbox checked, and the text filled out, a sub-query will be added to the search, joined by an "AND". I need a fairly fine-tuned control over the sub-queries, because they have their specifics. For instance, "ON YOMI" is a list of strings on the target object, so the query would look like this:

```
Where(k => k.OnYomi.Contains(tb_OnYomi.Text))
```

"Meaning" wants to do a fulltext search, something like String.Contains or LIKE, "Stroke count" will require some parsing, because it has to support ranges, for instance if you type 5-8, the query should look like this: (x >=5 && x <=8). "Other" needs to target a different property based on which value is selected in the combo box.

I've found this on MSDN, and frankly, I can't make heads or tails of it:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx

Could someone provide a better explanation or a more comprehensible example? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression tree solution is overkill. If you start with an `IQueryable`, you can dynamically add predicates like this and then when you enumerate the results at the end, it will process only once with all predicates (dynamically) combined:

```
var data = sourceData.AsQueryable();

if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb_OnYomi.Text))
    data = data.Where(k => k.OnYomi.Contains(tb_OnYomi.Text))

if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb_KunYomi.Text))
    data = data.Where(k => k.KunYomi.Contains(tb_KunYomi.Text))

// etc

var result = data.ToList();    // evaluates all dynamically added predicates at once.

// display result to the user.
```